# Reference Error: HTML Element not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using this package https://github.com/ingmarh/scroll-shadow-element with Typescript and I get the following error. I just have the  element surrounding a scrollable div. It works as intended but this error stills shows up.

```
error - ../../node_modules/scroll-shadow-element/dist/index.js (4:0) @ eval
error - ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/davidzhu/uabc-portal/packages/client/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/app/select-session/page.tsx:13:79)
    at (sc_client)/./src/app/select-session/page.tsx (/Users/davidzhu/uabc-portal/packages/client/.next/server/app/select-session/page.js:1591:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/davidzhu/uabc-portal/packages/client/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
```